# Firebase database Indexing Issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my customer database is like this:

```
{
    "customers": {
        "9115625853": {
            "address": "16-37-4/3, Innespeta, Rajahmundry 533101",
            "adhaar": "1111-2222-3333",
            "currentPackage": {
                "activation": "2016-11-22",
                "dataConsumed": 5905580032,
                "dataTotal": 21474836480,
                "expiry": "2016-12-22",
                "packageName": "5MB-20GB",
                "speedDown": "5 Mbps",
                "speedUp": "5 Mbps"
            },
            "email": "sureshk@gmail.com",
            "mobileno": "9115625853",
            "name": "Suresh Kumar P",
            "registered": "2016-11-22"
        },
        "7032906292": {
            "address": "46-17-24, Danavaipeta, Rajahmundry 533103",
            "adhaar": "5555-2342-3633",
            "currentPackage": {
                "activation": "2016-11-12",
                "dataConsumed": 18253611008,
                "dataTotal": 21474836480,
                "expiry": "2016-12-12",
                "packageName": "5MB-20GB",
                "speedDown": "5 Mbps",
                "speedUp": "5 Mbps"
            },
            "email": "lakshman@laurel.solutions",
            "mobileno": "7032906292",
            "name": "Lakshman Rao Pilaka",
            "registered": "2016-11-12"
        },
        "9165263347": {
            "address": "722 Junius Street, Grazierville, Indiana, 7463",
            "adhaar": "3935-1768-7293",
            "email": "mannray@biospan.com",
            "name": "Mann Ray",
            "phone": 9165263347,
            "registered": "2016-09-04"
        }
    }
}
```

I want an event to be fired when a child is added to the customer database where the `currentPackage` is not applied (ie when a customer like `9165263347 - Mann Ray`) is added.

I have written code like this

```
firebase.database().ref('customers/')
  .orderByChild('currentPackage')
  .equalTo(null)
  .once('child_added')
  .then(function(snapshot) {

       // My Code

 });
```

I get an error

> **Uncaught (in promise) Error: No index defined for currentPackage(…)**

My Firebase rules are as follows

```
   {
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "packages": {
            ".indexOn": "active"
        },
        "customers": {
            ".indexOn": "currentPackage"
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure, there is an error in the rule definition but somehow I am unable to get over it.

Please help.

thanks.

Comment: Everything here looks fine except for the unrelated use of once(), which is probably not what you actually wanted (you're trying to turn the realtime event stream into a CRUD operation). So something in your code/setup must not match what you've posted here.

Comment: I just up a jsbin with your code+JSON and get a warning, but no error.  Can you have a look at my jsbin to see how your case is different: http://jsbin.com/yeyapuk/edit?js,console

Comment: Also: if I copy/paste the index you have, the warning disappears.